How to configure ESLint rule to add blank line between test/test.beforeAll/test.beforeEach/test.afterEach/test.afterAll in Playwright test?
I want to update my .eslintrc.js to set up the rule that it requires a blank line between the test.beforeAll, test.beforeEach, test, test.afterAll, test.afterEach in the test code using Playwright
// test-login.test.js

const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
let context;

test.describe('test login', () => {
  test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
    context = await browser.newContext({ storageState: 'user1.json' });
  });
  test.beforeEach(async ({ browser }) => {
    page = await context.newPage();
  });
  test.afterAll(async () => {
    await context.close();
  });
  test.afterEach(async () => {
    await context.close();
  });
  test('test login with valid account', async () => {
  // test code...
  });
  test('test login with invalid account', async () => {
  // test code...
  });
  test('test login with invalid password', async () => {
  // test code...
  });
});

I tried to set up the rule as following but it's not working
// .eslintrc.js

module.exports = {
  env: {
    es2021: true,
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'google',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'plugin:playwright/recommended',
    'prettier'
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2021,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  root: true,
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    'padding-line-between-statements': [
      'warn',
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'function' },
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'block-like' },
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: '*', next: 'block' },
      { blankLine: 'always', prev: 'function', next: 'function' }
    ],
    '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
    'playwright/no-wait-for-timeout': 'off',
    'camelcase': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': [
      'warn',
      {
        selector: 'variable',
        format: ['camelCase', 'UPPER_CASE', 'PascalCase'],
      },
    ],
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'warn',
      {
        endOfLine: 'auto',
        singleQuote: true,
        parser: 'flow',
        printWidth: 140
      }
    ],
    'new-cap': 'warn',
    'max-len': 'off',
    'valid-jsdoc': 'warn',
    'require-jsdoc': 'off',
    'linebreak-style': 'off',
    'no-unused-vars': 'warn',
    'spaced-comment': 'warn'
  }
};


I'm actually looking for that same thing, I'm using vitest as a test runner, so probably this won't work for me, but if by any chance you are using Jest, this might work for you:
https://github.com/dangreenisrael/eslint-plugin-jest-formatting/blob/master/docs/rules/padding-around-all.md
This is a plugin for jest that has rules for what you are looking for:

padding-around-after-all-blocks
padding-around-after-each-blocks
padding-around-before-all-blocks
padding-around-before-each-blocks
padding-around-expect-groups
padding-around-describe-blocks
padding-around-test-blocks

Since I wasn't able to use that plugin in my project I was playing around with the rule's STATEMENT_TYPES, and this seemed to work fine in my test files:
'padding-line-between-statements': [
  'error', 
  {
    blankLine: 'always',
    prev: 'multiline-expression',
    next: 'multiline-expression'
  }
]

